# can't import 'torchtext' module in jupyter notebook while using pytorch

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pytorch, torchtext

[image]

I installed pytorch using anaconda3 and my created virtual conda environment named 'torchTest'. 
I installed all the modules needed but, codes doesn't work in jupyter python.

I installed torchtext using 
1.pip install https://github.com/pytorch/text/archive/master.zip
2.and also pip install torchtext too. 
all I mentioned successfully downloaded in my MAC OS X, but can't get what's wrong with my Jupyter notebook..

Answer (score 2):

After having the same issue with torchtext from within my jupyterlab, I opened an issue on Github at the [jupyterlab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5025) project as well as at the [torchtext](https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/360) repository.

My current solution is to add the PYTHONPATH from the Anaconda env.

The Anaconda path is usually like that `$HOME/anaconda/bin`

You can add it from within Jupyter Lab/Notebook like that:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/some/path/to/add")

import torchtext
```